# What's wrong with this method to read the position of a <div> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a persistent-header for my website. I wrote the following codes which does not work. While I am doing debugging I find it cannot even read the correct position of the div and that is the problem. Here is the code:

```
<script>
function UpdateTableHeaders() {

      /*var el             = $("#top_menu", this);
      var offset         = el.offset();
      var scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop();
      var floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this);


       if (scrollTop > offset.top) {
           floatingHeader.css(
            "visibility", "visible"
           );
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css(
            "visibility", "hidden"
           );      
       }; */
       //following lines is the code I have tried in turns to see if it can actually read the correct position or not
       $("#content").append( "position top:" + $('#top_menu').position().top);
       $("#content").append( "position top:" + $('#top_menu').offset().top);
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;


       clonedHeaderRow = $("#top_menu", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .addClass("floatingHeader");



   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

However, the output answer doesn't seems to be correct. Here is the output when I scroll the page:

position top:101.45001220703125position top:101.41668701171875position top:101.41668701171875position top:101.04998779296875position top:101.16668701171875position top:101.39999389648438position top:100.63333129882812position top:100.98333740234375position top:101.33331298828125position top:100.79998779296875position top:101.21665954589844position top:101.10000610351562position top:100.63333129882812position top:101.05000305175781position top:100.93333435058594position top:101.23333740234375position top:101.41667175292969position top:100.60000610351562position top:100.71665954589844position top:101.18333435058594position top:100.53334045410156position top:101.23333740234375position top:101.35000610351562position top:100.69999694824219position top:101.05000305175781position top:100.51666259765625position top:100.63333129882812position top:100.86666870117188position top:101.33332824707031position top:100.91667175292969

it fluctuates around 100. Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong?

Thank in advance for any help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What do you mean by persist header?

Comment: sorry, it's typo. I mean persistent header. I think you must have seen some website that when you scroll down the page, the header is still there. That's what I want to achieve. Do you any easier way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it this way. Use css `position : fixed` on your header instead.

Comment: hm, my header is actually not at the very top of the page. In fact it is in somewhere in the middle. What I am trying to do is when I scroll down the page and at the time the header touches the very top, it stays there. Therefore I can't simply use position: fixed on the header for this purpose.

Comment: Then detect scroll position of the page with `$(window).scrolltop()`, and if its far enough down, switch the header to position fixed.

Comment: yes, that's what I tried to do. I tried if($(window).scrolltop > $('#top_menu').position().top){//then do it here}. However, the event isn't triggered even when the header passes the very top. Then I tried to debug it and I find that $('#top_menu').position().top isn't showing me the correct cordinates.

Comment: what happens if you log `$(window).scrollTop()` ? Can I see a link to the page?

Comment: That's because you need to calculate the position of the header every time you scroll, so something like `$(window).scroll(function(){//do your calculation here});` should work.

Comment: @GuyFawkes he is doing exactly that, its near the end of his code sample.